# How to sort ToggleButton listener and AsyncTask call?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, toggle, listener

I will try to set the question without pasting any code because will be probably more clear.

I have an android application with one ToggleButton. When the ToggleButton is "ON" it starts a communication using sockets in an AsyncTask and when ToggleButton is "OFF" it stops the communication.
I am using the event setOnCheckedChangeListener to detect the changes in the button.

Wich one will be the right way to sort all the code? Do I set the listener on the UI thread, call from the UI the asyncTask and return from the asyncTask the socket witch I have established connection with?
I will need to know witch socket is open to close it once the ToggleButton is switched off...

It looks a little bit messy to me, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I want to ask one thing. Suppose user clicks ToggleButton very frequently so every time it will create AsyncTask and if you are creating socket in asynctask then it will create socket every time or not. AsyncTask you may be using because there may be some heavy task. So you sure that if you will click very rapidly then it will close all sockets.

Comment: The first thing that I do in the asyncTask is to disable the button until the socket has been created.

Comment: I think you can easily close your socket in your asyncTask just create broadcast sender and receiver. Receive broadcast in asyncTask and then close socket. In this way you need not to maintain any object to close your socket. As soon as you will send broadcast it will close socket in respective asynctask.

Comment: If you need example of braodcast sender and receiver that I can post.

Comment: It would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There can be several possible ways. You can use broadcast sender and receiver for you case.

Steps mentioned below:

Step 1: Create a broadcast receiver in your AsyncTask to receive broadcast from your activity.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("close_socket")) {
                // close your socket here.
            }
        }
    };
```

Step 2: Register your receiver after creating your broadcast receiver.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("close_socket");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Step 3: Send broadcast from your activity to close socket.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("close_socket");
SendBroadcast(intent);
```

Wherever you have registered your broadcast receiver it will automatically receive broadcast and close socket. Hope it will help you.