# add icons in dynamic list view using android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am new in android and i am using list view that is coming from the database . Now , I want to add two icons in it , one for edit and one for delete. Here is my java code that is currently working

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
      List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

      try {
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsonChildNode.optString("cat_name");
        number = jsonChildNode.optString("cat_id");
        String outPut = name /*+ "-" + number*/;
        employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
       }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
      listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
     }

     private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number)      {
      HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
      return employeeNameNo;
     }
```

can anyone tell me how to edit it to add the icons ?

Comment: If you want to add icons in each row then you need to create custom adapter.

Comment: take a look at to this answer for custom adapter http://stackoverflow.com/a/16292942/1589566

Comment: I have to add icon in each row @BharatSharma

Comment: I am new and this kind of stuff confuse me @inankupeli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told you are new so I am creating a listview similar to your needs. If you are still facing any problem then you can ask. There can be other methods also but I have followed below one.

I have created it in three steps:
1. Create a listview layout in XML.
2. Create a layout for your row which you will inflate and set on listview row.
3. Create a custom adapter by extending arrayadapter.
4. Setting custom adapter.

Step 1: Create a listview layout in XML.

Below given XML code will create a listview for you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2: Create a layout for your row which you will inflate and set on listview row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 3:Create a custom adapter by extending arrayadapter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class my_list_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> labels;

    public my_list_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> labels) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, labels);
        this.context = context;
        this.labels = labels;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView1;
        public ImageButton icon_1;
        public ImageButton icon_2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        ViewHolder holder;

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.icon_1 = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            holder.icon_2 = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView1.setText(labels.get(position));   
        holder.icon_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "bb icon 1 item clicked position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            }
        });
        holder.icon_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "bb icon 2 item clicked position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Step 4: Setting custom adapter.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            labels.add ("item " + i);
        }
        my_list_adapter adapter = new my_list_adapter(this, labels);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I think above example can help you. Try to get the concept. If you are facing any problem then you can ask. I will try to help you.

Comment: thank you so much it works i have one last question i have to edit the entry so for that i need the button across each i have tried to pass by creating object but that didn't worked

Comment: I am not getting what you are actually asking. What you want to update after clicking on edit button.

Comment: you have placed two buttons i want to perform action on click in which the variable is getting passed with it

Comment: On click listner is already there in customadapter for both images. You can use it for you requirement. Position is also available there.

Comment: if i add this 

Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeleteCategory.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", ids.get(position));
    context.startActivity(intent);

will it work ?

Comment: It should work you need to pass your context from your parent activity. But if you will use broadcast sender and receiver then it will definitely work.

Comment: If you need example of broadcast sender and receiver then here it is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680280/how-to-sort-togglebutton-listener-and-asynctask-call

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomArray adapter to add edit/delete button. This [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) will help you. please check it.

Comment: but my data is coming from database

Comment: ok no problem, here you need to update the data with your fetch data from database, that's you can do easily, you know it. how to do.

Comment: yeah i am just asking in my current code where i have to edit ?

Comment: instead of calling SimpleAdapter  call your customAdapter and insert the value to your CustomAdapter

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you have to use ur custom adapter

means extends BaseAdapter

and try to implement all methods in that adapter.

Comment: can you write the sample code here as i am new , these things are quite confusing for me

Comment: Hey here he is given an example right http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ just have a look it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

**None of the tutorials are going to help you**, because none show how to put a listener on a button in a listview in the getView() method of a custom ArrayAdapter and show you how to figure out what item in the listviev owns that button.  Even if there is a way to do this, you then have to figure out how (from the ArrayAdapter class) to call a method back in your Activity or Fragment, where you can then act on that item.

So, this leaves you with several options.  Instead of buttons, you need to respond to clicks/presses on the list item itself.  This is done by adding an OnItemClickListener or OnItemLongClickListener to the listview.  You can then respond to these actions in several ways:

- A context menu, where the user can select the option to delete or
  edit the item (using a listview of menu options).
- A pop-up Dialog that does the same thing with buttons.  Ot it could put them in edit mode and have a delete button too.

Since you are going to need to write a Dialog for the editing of the item, I would go with the Dialog option.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing if you're new to Android, but there's no shortcut in learning how to do it. Try this tutorial as well, I found it pretty helpful:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter